# How do I grant full network access for the LOCAL SYSTEM account in a Workgroup

Tags: networking, workgroup

How do I grant full network access for the LOCAL SYSTEM account in a Workgroup. Not a domain. I have some services that do not work under the LOCAL SYSTEM account that needs to access the network

Comment: When you say full network access - do you mean for a service to be able to access internet or connect to remote resources? Or to grant access on the target system for your service (running under local system account) to be able to authenticate to?

Comment: I need the a service to connect to resources. It works fine if I logon the service as a local admin user, but not if I use LOCAL SYSTEM